# Как обращаться к методам класса, заданного динамически?

Tags: java, android

В текущем классе необходимо программно определять имя другого класса (вида `"ClassNumPath + i"` ) и далее вызывать его методы.

Файлы классов `ClassNumPath0.java` (а так же `ClassNumPath1.java` .. `ClassNumPath5.java`) существуют и их методы вызываются без ошибок, если обращаться к ним в коде напрямую, например:

```
ClassNumPath0.initPositions();
```

или

```
ClassNumPath4.initPositions();
```

.. то никаких проблем нет - все работает как надо, отрисовка в `onDraw` производится и прочее... Но мне нужно определять имя класса `ClassNumPathХ`  динамически и иметь возможность менять это имя имя класса по ходу действия.

Часть кода над которым я бьюсь:

```
public class ClassNumPath extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
...
   int currentNum = 5;
   String currentClassName;
   Class cClass;
...

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   if (needInitialazation) {
      currentClassName = "com.mytestapp.testapp.ClassNumPath" + currentNum;
      cClass = Class.forName(currentClassName);

      cClass.initPositions(); // Ошибка: Cannot resolve method 'initPositions()'
      ClassNumPath5.initPositions(); // А это работает правильно

      Log.d("INF", "currentClassName = " + currentClassName);
      Log.d("INF", "cClass = " + cClass);
      // Эти логи выдают правильное имя класса com.mytestapp.testapp.ClassNumPath5
   }
   ...
   cClass.checkState(); // Ошибка: Cannot resolve method 'checkState()'
   ClassNumPath5.checkState(); // А это работает правильно
   ...
}
```

Итак, вопрос:

Каким образом можно обращаться к методам класса, чье имя было задано динамически?

Или, пожалуйста, подскажите вариант как по-другому решить задачу. Не хочется выстраивать большую конструкцию с операторами типа Case с выбором нужного имени класса в зависимости от значения currentNum, так как классов `ClassNumPathХ` может быть более 100 штук.

Comment: У них есть общий интерфейс?

Comment: Нет.

Что нужно сделать?

Comment: Создать интерфейс, который реализуют все эти классы `ClassNumPath1` - `ClassNumPathN`. Далее, например, поместить в массив по одному объекту от каждого класса, после чего вызывать `myClasses[currentNum].initPositions()`. Можно и более аккуратно подойти к этому решению, но "хотя бы так".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодарю @nofate за помощь!
Я использовал предложенное им Решение №2 с объявлением интерфейса.
Действительно, все методы в пронумерованных классах `ClassNumPathX` одинаковы и вовсе не обязаны быть статическими.
Единственное замечание, в строке:

```
 IClassNumPath classNumPath = (IClassNumPath) clazz.newInstance();
```

Android Studio выдавал ошибку на `IClassNumPath`, поэтому я заменил его на название интерфейса `ClassNumPath` (без префикса `I`):

---

### В итоге решение получилось такое:

В классе `ClassNumPath` объявил интерфейс `NumPath` с набором общих методов для всех нумерованных классов 'ClassNumPathX`

```
 public class ClassNumPath extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    ...
    public static NumPath cNumPath;
    ...
    // дать имя ClassNumPath интерфейсу внутри класса ClassNumPath уже нельзя
    public interface NumPath {
       void initPositions();
       void checkState();
    }
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       if (needInitialazation) {
          currentClassName = "com.mytestapp.testapp.ClassNumPath" + currentNum;
          Class clazz = Class.forName(currentClassName);
          NumPath cNumPath = (NumPath) clazz.newInstance();
          cNumPath.initPositions();
       }
       ...
       // Поскольку cNumPath объявлен как public, то можно пользоваться им в любом месте
       cNumPath.checkState();
    ...
    }
}
```

В самих нумерованных классах `ClassNumPathХ` даже и не пришлось ничего особо менять. Только добавил `implements ClassNumPath.NumPath` и `@Override` к методам и убрал из них `static`:

```
public class ClassNumPath4 implements ClassNumPath.NumPath {
   ...
   @Override
   public void initPositions() {
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public void checkState() {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Начнем со строки

```
Class cClass;
```

Класс [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) в Java представляет собой метаинформацию о некотором классе - о его полях, методах и прочем. У любого класса есть поле `class`, которое содержит экземпляр типа `Class`.

Когда вы вызываете `Class.forName` вы создаете не экземпляр целевого класса, а экземпляр такого метаописания целевого класса. Поэтому вы и не можете вызвать ни `initPositions()`, ни `checkState()` - таких методов у `Class` попросту нет.

Мы всегда можем создать новый экземпляр целевого класса из его метаописания, при помощи метода [`Class.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()). Это выглядит так:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(currentClassName);
Object a = clazz.newInstance();
```

Поскольку в момент написания кода и компиляции ни мы ни jvm еще не знает, что это будет за класс, мы вынуждены сохранить экземпляр в переменной типа `Object`. Однако это лишает нас возможности "дотянуться" до нужных методов.

### Решение 1. Грубо и "в лоб"

Разберемся, что можно сделать. Из приведенного вами кода следует, что методы `initPositions()` и `checkState()` статические. Это не очень здорово, потому что единственный способ вызвать их - рефлексия и в общем случае в клиентском (не системном/библиотечном) коде не стоит так делать.

Итак, нам нужно получить из экземпляра `Class` метаинформацию о методе `initPositions()` и заставить метод исполниться. Для этого у нас в распоряжении есть [`Class.getDeclaredMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)), возвращающий экземпляр типа [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html).  В свою очередь, в классе `Method` есть метод [`invoke(Object obj, Object... args)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)), позволяющий выполнить описываемый классом метод. Все вместе это будет выглядеть так:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(currentClassName);
Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("initPositions");
m.invoke(null); // параметр null - т.к. метод статический и не требует экземпляр класса
```

Метод выполнится, но все это не очень здорово, т.к. мы напрямую работаем с кишками jvm.

---

### Решение 2. Пересмотр дизайна классов

Вообще говоря, потребность вызывать методы классов через рефлексию должна натолкнуть на мысль в дизайне классов. Я не знаю, решаемой вами задачи, но для начала стоит избавиться от статических методов и вынести их в общий интерфейс.

То есть, объявить интерфейс, что-то вроде:

```
public interface IClassNumPath {
    void initPositions();
    void checkState();
    // ... другие методы общие для классов  
}
```

и реализовать этот интерфейс в ваших классах `ClassNumPath1`, `ClassNumPath2`, и т.д.

Теперь при создании экземпляра из `Class` мы сможем присвоить его переменной типа `IClassNumPath` и вызывать методы напрямую:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(currentClassName);
IClassNumPath classNumPath = (IClassNumPath) clazz.newInstance();
classNumPath.initPositions(); // все честно и без рефлексии.
```

Если статическое состояние крайне необходимо - рассмотрите возможность вынесения его в отдельный общий класс и передачу в экземпляры `IClassNumPath` через сеттер.

Comment: По поводу второго решения меня беспокоят как минимум три момента: 1. В конструктор объекта не передать аргументы. 2. Каждый раз создаётся новый объект - сохранить состояние не получится. 3. Нет никакой уверенности в том, что такой класс (например, `ClassNumPath14`) вообще существует. Если на начальном этапе можно всё отладить, чтобы никаких `ClassNotFoundException` не было, то при дальнейших изменениях в коде вполне можно забыть поменять логику здесь, потому что ошибок компиляции никаких не будет. Я не говорю, что это не ответ на вопрос - вопрос решают оба варианта.

Comment: Я исходил из гипотезы, что имена классов и их количество не известны на этапе компиляции. Замечания вполне логичны и вытекают из самой постановки вопроса.

Comment: @Nofate очень благодарен за подсказку!

Я использовал Решение №2 с объявлением интерфейса. 

Действительно, все методы в пронумерованных классах `ClassNumPath` одинаковы и вовсе не обязаны быть статическими.

Единственное замечание, в строке:


     IClassNumPath classNumPath = (ClassNumPath) clazz.newInstance();

Android Studio выдавал ошибку на `IClassNumPath`, поэтому я заменил его на название интерфейса `ClassNumPath` (без префикса I).